# Time Splash Screen Displayed for Matlab MCC Executable

Tags: matlab, splash-screen, matlab-compiler

I am running Matlab 2017a on Windows 7.

I have built an executable, from Matlab code, using mcc with the -mve flags.  I put the resulting executable (.exe) in a directory with a PNG file, splash.png.  When I click on the executable icon, the splash screen is dispalyed for about half the time the MCR takes to load up.  Is there a way to modify the time the splash screen is displayed?